# Spyder IDE environment in Python

Tags: python, spyder

I am currently using Spyder and have been for a long time, however I downloaded anaconda recently and started using Spyder for Python 3.5 which gives me several problems.

Whenever I run a script in the Python Console, I have to run it twice and then when I am finished running it and want to run a new I have to kill the current process and reload it.

I am currently using some scripts with threading, but that never used to be a problem before I upgraded, anyone have similar experiences and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder developer here*) We're aware of these problems in the Python console, but unfortunately we don't know how to fix them.

Please use the IPython console instead because the Python console is going to be removed in Spyder **3.2**.

Answer (score 0):

I observe some problems of users about Spyder Console.Effective example for solution;

via Anaconda prompt:

```
conda create -n spyder-env spyder=4
conda env list
conda activate speder-env
spyder
```